# Is there a root free solution for the 6s challenge?

Tags: formation-of-numbers

So the 6s challenge consist of taking a number from 0 to 10 and, using only "common" operations and the number three times, obtaining the number 6.

For example: $(0!+0!+0!)! = 6$ and $(4 - (4/4))! = 6$.

Now, for all the numbers from 0 to 7 you can find a solution that doesn't involve using any roots (check this video for possible solutions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2vkrxvh76c), but every solution I've came across, for 8,9 and 10 uses them.

For example: $8 - \sqrt(\sqrt(8+8)) = 6$ and $(\sqrt(9))! + 9-9 = 6$

My question is if you know any solution for 8,9 and 10 that uses only $+,-,\cdot,\div,(,)$ and $!$.

Comment: I'm pretty certain there's no "rootless" solution with these rules. Even if we allowed for writing the digits together, using the decimal point, and exponentiation, it seems very difficult.

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution for 8:

> If I can use !! with interpretation as double factorial, we have
>  $((8!!)/8)/8 = ((8\cdot6\cdot4\cdot2)/8)/8=6$

Answer (score 4):

Solution using $10$:

> $\big((10!!)_!\big)_!-\frac{10}{\Big(\big((10!!)_!\big)_!\Big)_!} = (3840_!)_!-\frac{10}{\big((3840_!)_!\big)_!} = 38_!-\frac{10}{(38_!)_!} = 11-\frac{10}{11_!} = 11-\frac{10}{2} = 11-5=6$ where $(x)_!$ is the [factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system).

Another solution using $10$ which I don't regard as an answer though (a silly one) is:

> $10+10+10 = 6$ (binary $2+2+2=6$)

Solution using two $9$s:

> $$\Bigg(\frac{(9!!)_!}{9}\Bigg)! = \Bigg(\frac{945_!}{9}\Bigg)!=\Bigg(\frac{27}{9}\Bigg)!=6$$

If we are allowed to use another mathematical operator $\%$ (modulus, a close relative of division) then the solution using three $9$s is:

> $$\Bigg(\frac{(9!!)_!}{9}\Bigg)!\%9 = \Bigg(\frac{945_!}{9}\Bigg)!\%9=\Bigg(\frac{27}{9}\Bigg)!\%9=6\%9=6$$

Solution using just one mathematical operator $\bar{}$ ($1$'s complement) if allowed using $9$

> $\bar{9} = \overline{1001} = 0110 = 6$

Leading to three $9$s solution using two operations:

> $\bar{9}+9-9 = 6$

Also, an interesting thing to note is that

> $6 = 9$ (XS3 code) or using three $9$s as exprected $6=9+9-9 $

Another solution using $10$

> $\Big(-\big(-(10!!)_{-10}\big)_{-10}\Big)_{-!} = \Big(-\big(-3840_{-10}\big)_{-10}\Big)_{-!}= \Big(-2240_{-10}\Big)_{-!} = 1840_{-!} = 1\times (-1)^3\times 3! + 8\times (-1)^2 \times 2! + 4\times (-1)^1\times 1! = 6$ where $(x)_{-10}$ is the [negadecimal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base) and $(x)_{-!}$ is the negative factorial system.

Comment: That's only two 9s.